# How to merge the contents of different directories into one directory

Tags: windows, filesystems

I have my data stored on 2 NTFS volumes E: and F:. They both contain a directory called `Storage` that has multiple sub-directories, different on every drive, such as:

```
E:\Storage\My Stuff
E:\Storage\My Old Stuff
```

and

`F:\Storage\My New Stuff`.

I would like to have them all in one place, i.e. have a virtual drive X: that contains directory `Storage` whose contents is:

```
My Old Stuff
My New Stuff
My Stuff
```

Requirements:

- the content of `X:\Storage` has to be the combined contents of `E:\Storage` and `F:\Storage`.
- `X:\Storage` has to be a 'virtual' directory that does not contain actual data. I.e. I do not want to move the data from `E:\Storage` to `X:\Storage`.
- `X:\Storage` has to be browsable using Windows Explorer.
- changes made to the content of either `E:\Storage` and `F:\Storage` have to be visible in `X:\Storage`.
- if both `E:\Storage\Same` and `F:\Storage\Same` exist, then `X:\Storage` should contain both these directories -- not only one of them.
- `X:\Storage` is allowed to be read-only. Write access is nice-to-have though.

Should this be implemented as a virtual file system, or is it an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: What should happen when you attempt to store a file into the virtual folder?

Comment: Do the volumes themselves need to be separate at all?

Comment: This sounds a lot like [storage spaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/overview)

Comment: There is 2 problems at least. 1st: the folders may have full name duplicates - what  file must be shown in that case? if both - how do you want to distinguish them? 2nd: while storing the file onto such "combined" drive what volume must be this file stored onto?

Comment: Hi @Suiden I don't think that this is possible, but there is a very similar thing called Libraries, it allows you to see multiple folders as only one. Here you have a tutorial that seems easy to follow: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/libraries-great-feature-windows-7 you will have to check if it's available in your OS version.

Comment: @JohnDvorak: I would happy with read-only access for the virtual drive. @grawity Yes, the volumes have to be separated. @Akina You are right, this is a problem. At the moment i do not have duplicates in the `Storage` directory though. @Falk thank you for your suggestion, i'll try Libraries. I don't think I need more than a basic UI with search capabilities, anyway.

Comment: You can go in to disk management and mount the drives as folders on your C: drive. You could create a folder `C:\Storage` with two sub folders (A and B) and then mount drive 1 in that folder as StorageA and drive 2 as StorageB. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/assign-a-mount-point-folder-path-to-a-drive

Comment: Depend in on what you actually want to do and how you want it to work it might also be a use case for [Libraries (as mentioned)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/windows-libraries). It's pretty unclear what your requirements are. Maybe spend some time to make it a [good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Appleoddity This basically means to use symlinks for my two Storage folders. This is an interesting idea. Even better, I could create a bunch of symlinks that point to the Storage subdirectories and combine them in this way in C:\Storage. I'd have to write a PowerShell script for this though. It's a nice solution in case Libraries proves to not meet my expectations.

Comment: @Seth thank you for your suggestion. I hope the question makes more sense now.

Comment: @Falk Libraries looks good. If you can add it as an answer, I will approve it. Thank you!

Comment: Ill try to write a good quality answer with a bit of time, I'm currently typing with my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution, among others, would be to use a feature of Windows called Libraries.

It's a way of presenting the content of multiple directories in one single place as a virtual folder.

There are a lot of great tutorials on how to create and use libraries like this one: [What are libraries in Windows, and how to use them for organizing your files](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/libraries-great-feature-windows-7).

Comment: What I don't know how it's handled is the case of duplicated names, I'll edit my answer to complete this information if it's needed.

Comment: I made a new Library and included the two directories in it. The view showed two groups, one for each directory. I removed the groups (`right-click > Group by > (None)`) and got the contents of the two directories merged at the root of the library. I also added the `Folder Path` column to the view. In case of duplicates, they have the same name but different folder paths.